# SQL (Hive): using window functions while aggregating with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, presto, amazon-athena

I have the following table in [Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/what-is.html) ([Hive](https://hive.apache.org/)/[Presto](https://prestosql.io/)):

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tmp (
    id STRING,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP,
    location STRING,
    direction STRING
)
LOCATION 's3://path';
```

I need to aggregate and count on the `id` field and at the same time select `location` and `direction` that are relative to the latest `timestamp` within the group (partition again is on `id`).

So far I came up with the following query leveraging window functions first and group by after:

```sql
SELECT
    b.id,
    MAX(b.latest_location) AS "latest_location",  -- It seems it is not possible to use first_value() on GROUP BY
    MAX(b.latest_direction) AS "latest_direction",
    COUNT(*) AS "total"
FROM (
    SELECT
        a.id,
        first_value(a.location) OVER (PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY a.updated_at DESC) AS "latest_location",
        first_value(a.direction) OVER (PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY a.updated_at DESC) AS "latest_direction"
    FROM tmp a
) b
GROUP BY b.id;
```

I have first tried to do the group by aggregation and the window aggregation at the same time, but it seems that this is not allowed by the engine. Is it possible to write a more efficient query (maybe without the subquery)?

Comment: You do `select distinct` on the inner query and add `count(*) over (partition by a.id)`. It'll be shorter though I'm not sure that's going to change much internally regarding execution efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    id,
    first_value(a.location)  OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY updated_at DESC) AS latest_location,
    first_value(a.direction) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY updated_at DESC) AS latest_direction,
    count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id) as total
FROM tmp
```

In your original query, `max` was basically a dummy aggregate as all the rows have the same value. And `group by` was essentially doing what the `distinct` does here.

Answer (score 1):

adding to preferred answer -- consider being more formal with your window definition supporting DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) preference:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    id,
    first_value(a.location)  OVER w AS latest_location,
    first_value(a.direction) OVER w AS latest_direction,
    count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id) as total
    FROM tmp
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY updated_at DESC)
```

This will allow more complicated window definitions to be maintained exactly one place and guarantee that the same window logic is used for both column calculations.

Answer (score 0):

You can mix window functions and aggregation functions . . . but in the other direction:  aggregation first, then window functions.

That said, your query should be much faster if you eliminate aggregation.  Just use `row_number()` and filtering:

```
SELECT a.id, a.location, a.updated_at
FROM (SELECT a.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY a.updated_at DESC) AS seqnum
      FROM tmp a
     ) a
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```